# Crystal Reports Issue turning a string into a number

Tags: oracle, crystal-reports

I'm having one of those throw the computer out the window days.

I am working on a problem involving Crystal Reports (Version 10) and an Oracle Database (11g).

I am taking a view from the database that returns a string (varcahr2(50)) which is actually a number, when a basic SELECT * query is run on this view I get the number back in the format 000000000000100.00.

When this view is then used in Crystal Reports I can view the field data, but I can't sum the data as it is not a number.

I began, by attempting to using ToNumber on the field, to which Crystal's response was that the string was not numeric text. Ok fair enough, I went back to the view and ran TO_NUMBER, when this was then used in crystal it did not return any results. I also attempted to run TO_CHAR on the view so that I could hopefully import the field as text and then perform a ToNumber, yet the same as with the TO_NUMBER no records were displayed.

I've started new reports, I've started new views. No avail.

This seems to have something to do with how I am retrieving the data for the view.

In simplistic terms I'm pulling data from a table looking at two fields a Foreign Key and a Value field.

```
SELECT PRIMARY_KEY, 
       NVL(MAX(DECODE(FOREIGN_KEY, FOREIGN_KEY_OF_VALUE_I_NEED, VALUE_FIELD)), 0)
    FROM MY_TABLE  
    GROUP BY PRIMARY_KEY
```

When I attempted to put modify the result using TO_NUMBER or TO_CHAR I have used it around the VALUE_FIELD itself and the entire expression, wither way works when the run in a SQL statement. However any TO_NUMBER or TO_CHAR modification to the statement returns no results in Crystal Reports when the view is used.

This whole problem smacks of something that is a tick box or equivalent that I have overlooked.

Any suggestions of how to solve this issue or where I could go to look for an answer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the `DECODE` statement?  If the are equal, then use `VALUE_FIELD` or something else?

Comment: The decode is for the table I am pulling the value from, it's a legacy design, but essentially the table holds all kinds of values and the foreign key delineates what kind of value the value field is. For example, if the table holds, heights of people, ages of people and names of people each gets it's own key and then the table can be used by searching using a key to a contact table, every contact getting a height, age and name and these are then differentiated by their key. Not very elegant, but not something I can change either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue with how Crystal Reports deals with queries from a database. All I needed to do was contain my SQL statement within another Select Statement and on this instance of the column apply the TO_NUMBER so that Crystal Reports would recognize the column values as numbers.

Hopefully this helps someone out, as this was a terrible waste of an afternoon.

Answer (score 0):

I ran this query in SQL Developer:

```
SELECT xxx, to_number(xxx) yyy
FROM  (
  SELECT '000000000000100.00' XXX FROM DUAL
  )
```

Which resulted in:

```
XXX                 YYY
000000000000100.00  100
```

If your field is truly numeric, you could create a SQL Expression field to do the conversion:

```
-- {%NUMBER_FIELD}
TO_NUMBER(TABLE.VALUE_FIELD)
```

Comment: I did run a TO_NUMBER on the field, and confirmed it was truly a number by asking for the datatype which confirmed it. My issue was not that the SQL didn't work. It was that when TO_NUMBER was used Crystal Reports didn't show any results